# GeoCoordinateWatcher.TryStart doesn't work properly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, latitude-longitude

I'm having an issue with the following code, namely that it doesn't show a Permission Prompt, therefore I can't give the application access to my location and doesn't work.

```
public Tuple<double, double> GetDeviceLocation()
{
    GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

    watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

    GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;

    if (coord.IsUnknown != true)
    {
        return Tuple.Create(coord.Latitude, coord.Longitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code incorrect. This code given an error not all code paths return a value. You should write a return value out of condition if brackets

Comment: I have an else too, but I deemed it irrelevant to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked microsoft documents and there's something that catches my attention.

> The distance that must be moved, in meters, relative to the coordinate
> from the last PositionChanged event, before the location provider
> raises another PositionChanged event.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The default movement threshold is zero, which means that any
> change in location detected by the current location provider causes a
> PositionChanged event and an update in the Position property.

```
   // Get location
   CLocation myLocation = new CLocation();
   myLocation.GetLocationEvent();
```

You must be register **PostionChange** event to get location information

Use the location class (CLocation) where do you need.

[GeoLocation Information MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.movementthreshold?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Device_Location_GeoCoordinateWatcher_MovementThreshold)

```
    public class CLocation
   {
    GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;

    public void GetLocationEvent()
    {
        this.watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        this.watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
        bool started = this.watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
        if (!started)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GeoCoordinateWatcher timed out on start.");
        }
    }

    void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        PrintPosition(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);
    }

    void PrintPosition(double Latitude, double Longitude)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Latitude: {0}, Longitude {1}", Latitude, Longitude);
    }
}
```