# C# GeoLocation Watcher taking too long to get coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms, geolocation

I have created a Windows Form App for our works Windows Tablets (windows 10) to track location.

The class I have created is below:

```
class LocationServices
{
    private GeoCoordinateWatcher myWatcher;
    private bool fgWatcherStarted = false;

    public LocationServices()
    {

        myWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
        fgWatcherStarted = myWatcher.TryStart(true, System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
    }

    public LatLon GetDeviceLocation()
    {
        LatLon myReturn = new LatLon();
        System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate myPosition = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate();

        try
        {
            if (!fgWatcherStarted)
            {
                fgWatcherStarted = myWatcher.TryStart(true, System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
            }

            myPosition = myWatcher.Position.Location;

            if (myPosition.IsUnknown)
            {
                myReturn.Latitude = 0;
                myReturn.Longitude = 0;
                myReturn.strMessage = "Unknown Position";
            }
            else
            {
                myReturn.Latitude = myPosition.Latitude;
                myReturn.Longitude = myPosition.Longitude;
                myReturn.strMessage = myPosition.Course.ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            myReturn.Latitude = 0;
            myReturn.Longitude = 0;
            myReturn.strMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
        }

        return myReturn;
    }
}
```

In my code I am running through every few seconds and getting the location by calling the class above.

If I am connected to wifi (running from my desk) it gets the location instantly and works as expected, but from the device it returns 0 for a significant amount of time and then suddenly starts working and works perfectly fine with no issues.

Is there anything I can do to make this start quicker? I initially thought it could be the location/signal but I have tried loading in the same place and leaving it and once it initialises it works perfectly but it's the initial coordinates that take ages to load.

Comment: You may have proxy turned on and there is no proxy.  So you may be waiting up to 30 seconds for the proxy to timeout before you are getting results.

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though there needs to be a position change for it to return a value, see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52910209/6639187

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your way of getting the coordinates, I used to do the following method - hope this helps (run it in a console app and check as follows)

```
class Program
    {
        private static GeoCoordinateWatcher Watcher;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
            Watcher.StatusChanged += Watcher_StatusChanged;
            Watcher.Start();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void Watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Ready)
            {
                if (Watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
                {
                    Console.Write("Cannot find location");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Lat: " + Watcher.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Lon: " + Watcher.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```